# Autotools specifying install path of static library

Tags: c, autotools, automake

How can I install a library to `$(top_srcdir)/lib/foo.a`?

If I try to use:

`noinst_LIBRARIES=$(top_srcdir)/lib/foo.a
foo_a_SOURCES= foo.c foo.h bar.c, bar.h`

I get `library has foo_a as canonical name (possible typo)`

I have foo.* and bar.* in `$(top_srcdir)/foobar/`.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: You do not hardcode the location of a convenience library in autotools.

Comment: You might want to add a hook to move the library to the wished location after make. As i remember the rule was all-local. You can check it in the official documentation. I dont have computer at the moment

Comment: @VicenteAdolfoBoleaSánchez I guess I could add a hook but according to [this slide 34](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/dl/autotools.pdf) `libdir = exec-prefix/lib` so shouldnt the behaviour I am looking for be default if i use `AC_PREFIX_DEFAULT=(.)` ?

When I use `noinst_LIBRARIES=foo.a` with `AC_PREFIX_DEFAULT(.)` it builds to the directory of the Makefile.am (in my question example `top_srcdir/foobar` where I want it to build to `top_srcdir/lib`)

Comment: Add correspond programming language tag please!

Comment: @Sergii My question is related to autotools though, I am coding in C I guess but that does that matter?

Comment: I know core `C`. And I think if you've added some `C` fragments, it's has relation to question, and question should be tagged as good as it possible. Tag `autotools` I think has pure relation on your question header `noinst_LIBRARIES specify install path`. So please improve header name also.

Comment: I see, prefix_default with just set the default prefix of the installation of binaries and libraries. In your case you have `noinst` library. Thus, it wont be installed. 

Lets put it in a different way. What is the problem you want to solve by having a library placed in a specific folder of  the build directory?

Comment: Bad idea, because even if you get this working, it will break 'out-of-tree' builds. Use `$(top_builddir)` or `$(builddir)`.

Comment: @VicenteAdolfoBoleaSánchez Strictly for personal preference, I want all of my compiled libraries to be in one directory.

@BrettHale Okay,  I will change over to `$(top_builddir)` if i get this working

Comment: Normally the way that the intermediate (build) files are organized is left to autotools to decide. As an exercise of expertise is good to tweak even those little detail but not for more serious stuff since you might end up with an ad-hoc solution which is hard to maintain or explain . For this specific error the problem is that / characters are not recognized by autotools for noinst_LDLIBRARIES. How about make the noinst library installable so that you  can easily place it in the directory you want

Comment: @VicenteAdolfoBoleaSánchez The library doesnt need to be installed, it is solely needed to compile the application thats it. For own testing purposes I will just be using `make`, not `make install`, so it would be more convenient to keep it as `noinst` but if this proves be to much effort I will just leave it as is

Comment: Oh I see, so you need that library in an specific location to perform some tests which depends on that. I guess that there will be another program which uses those `noinst` libraries and expect it to find them in the specific directory. Is it correct? If so I will write an answer to solve that problem :)

Comment: @VicenteAdolfoBoleaSánchez Yes those are correct assumption thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the action you are trying to achieve is not standard, GNU/Autotools does not support that feature. Nevertheless, GNU/Autotools let the programmers to tweak their system by using local rules which extend the functionability of its Makefile rules.

For instance, to copy your library to an specific location you can write:

```pl
# Standard way
noinst_LDLIBRARIES = foo.a

# Here is where you tweak, all-local will be performed
# after compilation.
all-local:
  -cp $(builddir)/foo.* $(buildir)/libs
```

**Note** that `$(srcdir)` and `$(builddir)` are identical when you call `configure` in the same directory the configure script is place. When
you call `configure` from a different directory `buildir` and `srcdir` will 
differ.

#### Links

- [Extending Autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html)